# Code inside variable fires without being called?

Tags: javascript

I found the below code online to insert a clock into my website. In the final line of the startTime() function a variable t is declared. The code within t, however, appears to fire without t being called (this is evident because the clock works perfectly in the site).

Why is this code working?

I know from assigning functions as variables that those functions do not fire upon assignment but need to be called. I also tried the below code without assigning the setTimeout to t and it also works. What is the point of assigning it to a variable?

I'm new to javascript so any explanation that would help me understand what's going on here would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('timeLink').innerHTML = "Time: " +
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
```

Comment: `The code within t, however, appears to fire without t being called` Do you mean to say that `startTime()` is not called?

Comment: Probably you want to set the ``innerText`` and not ``innerHTML``, because if you want to set the ``innerHTML`` you should provide a **valid html** string something like ``document.getElementById('timeLink').innerHTML = "<p>hi</p>" ``.

Comment: @hamism `.innerText` is not standard and won't work in all browsers. `.innerHTML` does not require any HTML (despite its name) in the string.

Comment: @hamism pretty much any HTML element can contain only a text node, and not other elements, so passing in the string is just fine.

Comment: @ScottMarcus @Shomz i should say it is "better" that "should"  and i agree with you that it is fine to use ``.innerHTML`` but i mean if ``.innerText`` work for your needs why using ``.innerHTML``

Comment: @hamism `.innerText` won't work in all browsers and `.innerHTML` will. `.innerText` should not be used at all because of this.

Comment: @ScottMarcus  Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign a variable, the right side gets evaluated, and the result of that evaluation is put into the variable.

So if you write:

```
var a = 5 + 6;
```

Then the interpreter will evaluate 5 + 6, get a result of 11, and assign a to the number 11

The same goes for functions. If you write:

```
function someFunction() {
    return 9;
}
var x = someFunction();
```

The interpreter will evaluate `someFunction`, call the function, get a result of 9, and assign the variable to 9.

This applies in your example as well.

```
var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
```

The interpreter will:

1. evaluate the right side, `setTimeout(startTime, 500)`, which then
2. calls the function (which waits 500ms and then calls startTime)
3. get a result that is the id of the timer
4. assign that id to t.

**Summary**

Functions actually do fire upon assignment, so they can be evaluated to return the value that is assigned to the variable.

Hope that cleared it up!

Comment: Both `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` return a number that represents the specific instance of the timer. They always have. This return value is ESSENTIAL if you ever wish to stop the timer(s) using `clearTimeout()` or `clearInterval()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout  Additionally, functions DO NOT fire upon assignment. Functions are DATA in JavaScript. Assigning a function to a variable just stores the function in that variable. Most of your answer here is incorrect.

Comment: I don't know why you keep talking about these timers not being standardized across browsers. They are. They work the same in all modern browsers. Read the Mozilla link I provided. Your answer is still mostly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
 var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
```

means that after a 500 millisecond delay, the `startTime` function should be invoked. Since this code is inside of `startTime`, the function becomes recursive. The `t` variable will receive a number that represents the specific instance of the timer. This can be used later if you wish to cancel the timer, using the `clearTimeout()` function...You would pass it the reference to the timer that you want to cancel, like this:

```
clearTimeout(t);
```

Take a look at this Fiddle to see the actual value returned by `setTimeout()`: https://jsfiddle.net/34s2g1f4/6/

By the way, a much more simplified clock code would be:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   var timeLink = document.getElementById('timeLink');
   var t = null;

   // The parenthesis around this function make it a function
   // expression and the extra set of parenthesis at the end
   // cause the function to invoke itself. This syntax is also
   // known as an "Immediately Invoked Function Expression"
   (function startTime() {
      timeLink.innerHTML = "Time: " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
      t = setTimeout(startTime, 900);
   }());

});
```

This code updates the time every 900 milliseconds, rather than every 500 milliseconds (thus it calls itself nearly half as often, but still keeps the time accurate).

The `setTimeout()` function creates a "one-time" timer. After the timer goes off, the supplied function reference is invoked and that's the end of it, but in your case the supplied function reference is the function that contains `setTimeout()`, so after the first time the timer goes off, it calls the current function again, causing another "one-time" timer to be set up and so on. When a function invokes itself, it is called a "recursive function".

Another way to get this behavior would be to use `setInterval()`, which creates a repeating timer that invokes its function repeatedly at the interval you supply. It would look like this:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var timeLink = document.getElementById('timeLink');

   // Here, the call to start the timer is outside of the function
   // so startTime will not be recursive, it will just be called
   // repeatedly every 9/10's of a second.
   var t = setInterval(startTime, 900);
});

function startTime() {
   timeLink.innerHTML = "Time: " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

Despite what the accepted answer says (it's mostly wrong), `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` are standardized and have been for some time. From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

[image]

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout() is called and the return value is assigned to var t. The return value in this instance is an ID unique to this instance of setTimeout.